# Легковесная связь элементов стандартных контейнеров

Tags: c++, gcc, hashmap

Есть два стандартных контейнера, при вставке элементов в которые ссылки не ломаются (множество и список). Как связать их в карту так, чтобы по ссылке на элемент одного контейнера получать ссылку на другой? Использую ссылки, чтобы не выделять снова память для элементов обоих контейнеров + итераторы ломаются при рехешинге судя по документации. Вот что попробовал, но не хочет компилироваться:

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <forward_list>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

int main(){
    std::unordered_set<std::string> A;
    std::forward_list<std::string> B;

    std::unordered_map<std::reference_wrapper<decltype(A)::value_type>,
            std::reference_wrapper<decltype(B)::value_type>> AB_linked;
}
```

Comment: Приведите текст ошибки.

Comment: @älёxölüt очень много ошибок при инстанциации шаблона

Comment: Вероятно, проблема из-за хеш функции. Можно попробовать нечто [такое](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DWCqwgbUIJcEyG1g)

Comment: @älёxölüt я так и сделал, только вместо value_type взял const_pointer и всё

Comment: Ну, кстати, да. Проблема решена? :)

Comment: @älёxölüt да, получается так. Но было бы неплохо услышать, почему для `reference_wrapper` не работает в ответе

Comment: Приведите всё же [mcve] и текст ошибки. Пример можно оформить в виде того, что я дал по ссылке, т.е. со всеми инклюдами и т.п. (бери и компилируй). Ну и версию компилятора заодно. Для редактирования вопроса используйте ссылку [edit] под вопросом.

Comment: @älёxölüt сделал, текст ошибки слишком большой, чтобы приводить. Там они в разных файлах стандартной библиотеки появляются

Comment: Ну, [вот](https://wandbox.org/permlink/F2iv1HJhtpW7yIGr), первая ошибка: **static_assert failed "This hash only works for enumeration types"**. О чём я и говорил.

Comment: @älёxölüt ну в gcc у меня первая менее понятная *error: static assertion failed: hash function must be invocable with an argument of key type
       static_assert(__is_invocable<const _H1&, const _Key&>{}*

Comment: Я потому и говорю, что надо приводить больше информации в вопросе, чтобы потом в комментариях не расписывать простыни для уточнения.